How to get UniProt accession from amino acids sequence?
I would like to use the UniProt API in Python to get the UniProt accession given the sequence of amino acids, but I can't seem to find a way to do so, not from a sequence. Is there a way to do so, please? If yes, what to use? If no, what are manageable alternatives? Thank you

When it comes to sequence searching, the UniProt API can be a bit tricky. You can definitely do this, but you need to use their REST API and BLAST search. It's not as easy as querying with sequences, but it's still doable. Basically, you just submit the sequence to their BLAST endpoint and it will return results matching the UniProt number.
My advice.
Use the BLAST endpoint of the UniProt REST API (rest.uniprot.org/blast/run)
Submit your sequence and wait for the results
Look at the matches and find the most relevant one
If you want a simpler approach, there are several options:
If you know the protein name or organism, you can use them instead of searching
You can use the NCBI BLAST web service - it's more user-friendly and links back to UniProt
If you do this often, you may need to download the UniProt database and run a local BLAST search
def search_uniprot_by_sequence(sequence: str, identity_threshold: float = 0.9) -> List[Dict]:
    """
    Search UniProt database using a protein sequence.
    
    Args:
        sequence: Amino acid sequence to search
        identity_threshold: Minimum sequence identity (default 0.9 or 90%)
    
    Returns:
        List of dictionaries containing matches with UniProt accessions and metadata
    """
    # UniProt's BLAST API endpoint
    blast_api = "https://rest.uniprot.org/blast/run"
    blast_status = "https://rest.uniprot.org/blast/status/"
    blast_results = "https://rest.uniprot.org/blast/results/"
    
    # Parameters for BLAST search
    data = {
        "sequence": sequence,
        "database": "uniprotkb_swissprot",
        "program": "blastp",
        "matrix": "BLOSUM62",
        "threshold": 10,
        "taxons": None,
        "filter": "false"
    }
    
    # Submit BLAST search
    response = requests.post(blast_api, data=data)
    if not response.ok:
        raise Exception(f"BLAST search failed: {response.status_code}")
    
    job_id = response.json()["jobId"]
    
    # Poll for results
    while True:
        status_response = requests.get(blast_status + job_id)
        if not status_response.ok:
            raise Exception(f"Status check failed: {status_response.status_code}")
        
        status = status_response.json()["status"]
        if status == "FINISHED":
            break
        elif status in ["ERROR", "FAILURE", "NOT_FOUND"]:
            raise Exception(f"Search failed with status: {status}")
        
        time.sleep(5)  # Wait before checking again
    
    # Get results
    results_response = requests.get(blast_results + job_id)
    if not results_response.ok:
        raise Exception(f"Results retrieval failed: {results_response.status_code}")
    
    results = results_response.json()["results"]
    
    # Filter and format results
    matches = []
    for hit in results:
        identity = float(hit.get("identity", 0)) / 100
        if identity >= identity_threshold:
            matches.append({
                "uniprot_id": hit.get("id"),
                "identity": identity,
                "protein_name": hit.get("proteinName"),
                "organism": hit.get("organism"),
                "sequence_length": hit.get("sequenceLength")
            })
    
    return matches


Thank you! Unfortunately, blast_api = "https://rest.uniprot.org/blast/run" gives a 404 error

make sure you have 'requests' installed. if so, UniProt may have updated their API endpoints to re-use the API try
